# Why does a current mirror have low input resistance?

Tags: current-mirror

I know that the output resistance needs to be high otherwise the output current will vary depending on the load.  However,  I don't understand why the input resistance needs to be low?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The input of an ideal current mirror should look for the input circuit as a short, as it is connected in series. Otherwise it will load that circuit and affect the current.

The output of the ideal current mirror should be an *ideal current source*, which, as you correctly said, should have an infinite resistance (it can be seen in the case of mirroring `0A` current. In this case the output will effectively represent a disconnect).

Comment: In other words a  perfect receiver for a current source is a low impedance; the current received then depends minimally on the (low) impedance of the receiver, or the (high-but-not-infinite) impedance of the source.   Mismatched impedances guarantee that the sensitivity is to current, not impedance.